# google maps api and google search results are not matching

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, maps

The Results from the Google Search and google maps api
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json
both data is not matching there is huge difference in the results that are returned